# Send messages through a specific path

Tags: omnet++

I am new to Omnet++ and building my first network where a message has to go through a specific route. Here is a simplified version of a sample network I am working with.

[image]

When receiving a request, it has to go through a specific route. For example; A->B->E->D->E->C

My issue arises when dealing with gates. My first instinct was to create an `inout` gate specific to the connection between each module. So A->B would have its own `inout` gate, B->E would have it's own `inout` gate, etc. However, as the network grows, this results in a very high amount of gates to manage.

My second attempt was to create and `inout` gates array. My connections are as follow:

```
    A.nodeGates++ <--> B.nodeGates++;
    A.nodeGates++ <--> C.nodeGates++;
    A.nodeGates++ <--> D.nodeGates++;
    C.nodeGates++ <--> E.nodeGates++;
    B.nodeGates++ <--> E.nodeGates++;
    D.nodeGates++ <--> E.nodeGates++;
```

In the cpp file I would then call `send(msg, "nodeGates$o", indexId);` in my `handleMessage` function. Is there a way to map the indexId depending on the module name? For instance, when I am at module *A*, for the route A->B->E->D->E->C, I would dynamically find the indexId to go from *A* to *B*. Once at *B*, I would find the indexId to go to *E* and so on.

Is there a way to dynamically find the indexId between two nodes to follow a precise route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a given **output** `gate` you can call `getPathEndGate()` which would give you the gate on the far end of the connection. Calling `getOwnerModule()` on that gate would give you the module on the far end, and then calling `getFullName()` on that module would give you the name of that module. This way you can get the name of a module connected to a given output gate. You can make your routing decision based on that information.

```
gate("nodeGates$o", indexId)->getPathEndGate()->getOwnerModule()->getFullName()
```

see: https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cGate.html

Also note that you have to implement **source routing**, i.e you must store the required path of the packet in the packet itself when you create it, and on each hop, the node must drop one hop from this list and do the routing decision based on the next required node. This way the packet would go through the specified path and end at the final destination.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!